# Cannot get all record with specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table `property` and `property_meta`, the `property` table contains all the records and `property_meta` instead, contains all the feature and the depth details of each property.

I would like to search a property using the following optional parameters:

- title
- area id
- region id
- city id

the `property` table have the following structure:

```
| id | title | deleted
  1     test    0
  2     test2   0
```

and `property_meta` have this structure:

```
| id | property_id | meta_key        | meta_value  
  1       1           property_area      1208
  2       1           property_region    1207
  3       1           property_city      1237
  4       2           property_area      1208
  5       2           property_region    1207
  6       2           property_city      1237
```

I created the following query:

```
 SELECT p.* 
    FROM property p
    INNER JOIN property_meta pm ON p.id = pm.property_id 
    WHERE LOWER(p.name) LIKE concat("%%") AND p.deleted = 0 
    AND (pm.meta_key = 'property_area' AND pm.meta_value IN (1208)) 
    AND (pm.meta_key = 'property_region' AND pm.meta_value IN (1207)) 
    AND (pm.meta_key = 'property_city' AND pm.meta_value IN (1237))
    GROUP BY p.id
```

unfortunately this query return an empty result, but if I remove the following conditions:

```
 AND (pm.meta_key = 'property_region' AND pm.meta_value IN (1207)) 
 AND (pm.meta_key = 'property_city' AND pm.meta_value IN (1237))
```

I get both rows, which mistake I did?

Comment: You'd be better off with a properly designed relational database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can_'t be all valid by  one,row  because the and clause are exclusive when you run the query.

You have to check if all three are valid at once for example by sum like my example

So use

```
 SELECT 
    p.id
FROM
    property p
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        `property_id`
    FROM
        property_meta pm
    GROUP BY `property_id`
    HAVING SUM(pm.meta_key = 'property_area'
        AND pm.meta_value IN (1208)) + SUM(pm.meta_key = 'property_region'
        AND pm.meta_value IN (1207)) + SUM(pm.meta_key = 'property_city'
        AND pm.meta_value IN (1237)) = 3) pm ON p.id = pm.property_id
WHERE
    LOWER(p.title) LIKE CONCAT('%%')
        AND p.deleted = 0
GROUP BY p.id
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE property  (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `title` VARCHAR(5),
>   `deleted` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO property 
>   (`id`, `title`, `deleted`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'test', '0'),
>   ('2', 'test2', '0');
>
> CREATE TABLE property_meta  (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `property_id` INTEGER,
>   `meta_key` VARCHAR(15),
>   `meta_value` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO property_meta 
>   (`id`, `property_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', 'property_area', '1208'),
>   ('2', '1', 'property_region', '1207'),
>   ('3', '1', 'property_city', '1237'),
>   ('4', '2', 'property_area', '1208'),
>   ('5', '2', 'property_region', '1207'),
>   ('6', '2', 'property_city', '1237');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>  SELECT 
>     p.id
> FROM
>     property p
>         INNER JOIN
>     (SELECT 
>         `property_id`
>     FROM
>         property_meta pm
>     GROUP BY `property_id`
>     HAVING SUM(pm.meta_key = 'property_area'
>         AND pm.meta_value IN (1208)) + SUM(pm.meta_key = 'property_region'
>         AND pm.meta_value IN (1207)) + SUM(pm.meta_key = 'property_city'
>         AND pm.meta_value IN (1237)) = 3) pm ON p.id = pm.property_id
> WHERE
>     LOWER(p.title) LIKE CONCAT('%%')
>         AND p.deleted = 0
> GROUP BY p.id
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> |  2 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>  `property_id`
>
> FROM 
> property_meta pm
> GROUP BY  `property_id`
> HAVING  SUM(pm.meta_key = 'property_area' AND pm.meta_value IN (1208)) +
> SUM(pm.meta_key = 'property_region' AND pm.meta_value IN (1207)) +
> SUM(pm.meta_key = 'property_city' AND pm.meta_value IN (1237)) = 3
> ```
>
> ```
> | property_id |
> | ----------: |
> |           1 |
> |           2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94ebe841a553ef47456e85fb459f3994)*

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that one of your rows meets all the conditions. You should use 'OR' instead of 'AND':

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM property p
     INNER JOIN property_meta pm ON p.id = pm.property_id 
WHERE LOWER(p.name) LIKE concat("%%") AND p.deleted = 0 
      AND ((pm.meta_key = 'property_area' AND pm.meta_value IN (1208)) 
            OR (pm.meta_key = 'property_region' AND pm.meta_value IN (1207)) 
            OR (pm.meta_key = 'property_city' AND pm.meta_value IN (1237)))
GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OR not AND between the optional parameters.  There's no way a row's metavalue could be 1207 AND 1237

```
SELECT p.* 
    FROM property p
    INNER JOIN property_meta pm ON p.id = pm.property_id 
    WHERE LOWER(p.name) LIKE concat("%%") AND p.deleted = 0 
    AND 
    (
        (pm.meta_key = 'property_area' AND pm.meta_value IN (1208)) 
        OR (pm.meta_key = 'property_region' AND pm.meta_value IN (1207)) 
        OR (pm.meta_key = 'property_city' AND pm.meta_value IN (1237))
    )
    GROUP BY p.id
```